# why does 'today' return extra minutes on the end of a date

Tags: php

I need to get the first and last second of a given day in php. when I use this:

```
$date2 = strToTime('today');
echo Date('Y-m-d h:m:s', $date2) . "</br>";
```

I get `2013-03-24 12:03:00`.
but why the 3 extra minutes? It should say `12:00:00`. I need a solution that can work every single time even in weird leap year scenarios because this code will initiate payments.

http://ideone.com/H2JQ0D

Comment: chicago/central, and the server is just AMPPS running on my computer

Comment: Why the heck can't PHP be consistent with _anything_?  The docs linked from `strToTime` say use `HH:MM:II` and yet the `date` function uses `h:i:s`.  Grr!!

Comment: yes @MattBall nailed it indeed. I think at least one of these questions should stay open, it obviously is a common problem. Especially in March!

Comment: wait does closed just mean a question has been answered? I thought it ment the question was removed...

Comment: Closed means neither of those things. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/133242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `PHP` `m` is for months not minutes

Replace

```
echo Date('Y-m-d h:m:s', $date2)
                   ^--------------------- Months
```

with

```
echo Date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $date2)
                   ^--------------------- Correct Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
$firstSecond = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'; // first second of today
$lastSecond  = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59'; // last second of today
```

for some other day

```
$time = strtotime('yesterday');
$firstSecond = date('Y-m-d', $time) . ' 00:00:00'; // first second of yesterday
$lastSecond  = date('Y-m-d', $time) . ' 23:59:59'; // last second of yesterday
```

EDIT::

Now that I think of it. If the whole purpose is to see if a record lands on a current day you could easily do:

```
$recordTime = strtotime('2013-03-24 14:12:23');

if ($recordTime >= strtotime('today') && $recordTime < strtotime('tomorrow') {
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: _sometimes_ the last second of the day is at 24:00:00 ...